# How to get post image root URL?

Tags: wordpress, path, thumbnails

By using below code, I got Image url like `"http://localhost..."` but I need root path of that image from `"var/www/html/.... "`

```
 $FeaturedImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(
 $post->ID ), 'homepage-column1' );
```

Is there any way to get root path of the post thumbnail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$FeaturedImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID ),'homepage-column1' );
$uploads = wp_upload_dir();
$file_path = str_replace( $uploads['baseurl'], $uploads['basedir'], $FeaturedImage);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that!!